# Using Listview in a scroll view

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

In my app i did use scroll inside a Scrollview layout(root layout).when i did that the child  scroll stopped scrolling.For this i found a solution code

```
childlistview.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
            }

            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
        });
```

It solved the problem.But i can't understand this code.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `Scrollview` is parent whereas `ListView` is its child.

So, in normal case when you try to scroll, the `ScrollView` will intercept that event and the scroll of `ScrollView` will occur. It will not reach the `ListView` within as it is already handlled by the parent `ScrollView`.

However, when you set a `TouchListener` to the child `ListView` and override its the `onTouch()` as you have done, a different behaviour is observed.

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
```

This event happens when the first finger is pressed onto the screen.

```
  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

This will prevent the parent from intercepting the touch event, so that the child can handle the event appropriately.

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
```

This event fires when all fingers are off the screen.

```
  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

This will allow the parent to intercept the touch events thereafter, for rest of the screen leaving the childview.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: WelCome, Glad to share it with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

It simply disable the parent touch  of the child `View`. In your case it disable the parent( `ScrollView`) touch of child view (`v`).

Again if you want to enable the parent touch, simply pass `false` to the same method.

Hope it clears your doubt.